# Opencv Compilation fails at 30% on Mac

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, compilation, cmake

I'm working on MacOS 10.12.

I successfully ran `cmake` on the opencv files that I got from opencv.org. My python libraries are also linked. After I run `cmake`, I try to compile using the following command:

```
make -j4 #since mine is quad-core
```

I'm getting this error at 30% completion:

```
[ 30%] Built target libprotobuf
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any idea whats going wrong? I'm working in a virtual environment. Is that causing this error?

Comment: Have you tried to google based on error message ("runlib has no symbols")? See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929255/building-static-libraries-on-mac-using-cmake-and-gcc). BTW, for make error message *searchable*, include it into the question post **as text**, not as *image*.

Comment: Hey, I did some trial and error, and final found the loophole. `with_cuda=off` as `cmake` parameter solves the entire issue. I'm using it on macAir with no nvcc driver or gpu, hence cuda linking was giving an error.

Comment: Yeah. I will keep that in mind. I will post the error in text rather than images from hereon.